# How to override :order defined in a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have

```
class Authors 
has_many :books, :order => 'name ASC'
```

I am trying to query all the books sorted by name DESC

```
Authors.books.order('name DESC')
```

but the result is

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY name ASC, name DESC
```

and the results come back with the name sorted ASC

is there a way to remove the original order in the association or override it? Or is specifying an order in a relation a bad idea?

using Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder):

```
Authors.books.reorder('name DESC')
```

Comment: That's great! Couldn't find it documented anywhere though; where did you find it?

Comment: Actually, is this still valid? https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e0b76d6151821527f16b3f163abde3ebea1b2a50

Comment: @Christopher ~ Not by my reading. May I suggest (which you probably already deduced from that post) accepting @Jon's answer below?

Comment: Works also in Rails 5: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder

Answer (score 35):

`.reorder()` has been deprecated in Rails 3.0.3 in favor of `.except(:order).order()`

So use this:

```
Authors.books.except(:order).order('name DESC')
```

Comment: I don't see any deprecation warnings on rails 3.1.0.rc4 about #reorder, and `.except(:order).order()` doesn't exclude order clauses that are pulled in from associations.

Comment: `.except(:order).order()` **does** exclude order clauses defined on associations.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `reorder` being deprecated in Rails 3.2.8: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder

Comment: `reorder` is still valid in Rails 4.0.2: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/reorder

Answer (score -1):

```
Author.first.books.reverse_order
```